# Store the Contents of a Panel Control into a Cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I created a page, which allows users the option to show or hide it's content sections via a show/hide button. After clicking the show/hide button, the nested panels/content becomes visible or invisible based on the button selected, then the user may save the page by clicking a save button. Problem - (no errors) but, the page is not saving the users changes into the cookie. The page contains 2 panel controls that are nested in one main Panel control.

```
//Front End code - The save button
<asp:Button ID="savButton" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="savButton_Click" />

//psuedo code - The Panels
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSaveContent" runat="server"> //main Panel control 
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlWeatherAppCtrl" runat="server"> // panel content 1
         <div>Weather App Content</div>
     </Panel>
     <asp:Panel ID="StockAppCtrl" runat="server">   // panel content 2
           <div>Stock App Content</div>
      </Panel>
</Panel>

//Back-end code:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //get the cookie       
        if ((Request.Cookies["preferences"] != null))
        {
            pnlSaveContent.ID = Request.Cookies["preferences"]["savePg"];
        }
     }

 //set cookie
    protected void savButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["preferences"]["savePg"] = pnlSaveContent.ID;
        Response.Cookies["preferences"].Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
    }

 //end code
```

...the issue: The page is not saving the changes of the main panel control. Could someone please provide some guidance as to what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to save the cookie with `Response.Cookies.Add`:

```
protected void savButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["preferences"] != null ? 
        Request.Cookies["preferences"] :
        new HttpCookie("preferences");
    c.Values["savePg"] = pnlSaveContent.ID;
    c.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(c);
}
```

As for your comment... I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but maybe it is this. This will set the visibility of the panel depending on the value of the cookie (visibility is `false` if the ID matches the value of cookie).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the cookie       
    if ((Request.Cookies["preferences"] != null))
    {
        pnlSaveContent.Visible = !(pnlSaveContent.ID == Request.Cookies["preferences"]["savePg"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, ...does the cookie have to be retreived in the "Page Load" block? I place the above code onto the save button and when I click the hide button, the respective content panel goes into invisible state but once I navigate away from the page and come back, that same content panel is there again.

Comment: @user1724708 updated answer to show how to set visibility of panel based on the cookie value.

Comment: @user1724708 if you have more questions, you may need to create a new question. This answer shows how to fix your problem by appropriately saving a cookie and setting a panel visibility based on that cookie value.