# How to set visibility of panel based on the cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have a webpage that presents the user with basic information and two widget plugins; The page allows the options to show and/or hide either widgets by clicking a show/hide button (all good there). Then the user may save the page by clicking a save button that stores the page content(the master panel) into a cookie (problem here). The entire content section of the page is stored in a master panel control with the two widgets housed in a panel control of their own (see Design Code below):

...Design:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSaveContent" runat="server"> //master panel
   <asp:panel ID="pnlWeatherAppCtrl" runat="server">
        <div id="weatherwidget"> 
          <!-- the widget code for displaying the weather app -->
         </div>
   </panel>
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlStockAppCtrl" runat="server">
          <div id="stockwidget">
         <!-- the widget code for displaying the stock app -->
           </div>
   </panel>
  <div>   <!-- save button -->
       <asp:Button ID="savButton" runat="server" Text="Save Page" onclick="savButton_Click" />
  </div>   
</panel>  <!--end master panel-->
```

I have the page working so that when the user clicks the show or hide button, the respective widget section become visible or invisible, but when the save button is clicked, and the page is left, then returned to, both widgets will still show. Here is my code for the save button:

...code:

```
protected void savButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["preferences"];
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.Values["savePg"] = pnlSaveContent.ID;
            c.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
            Response.Cookies.Add(c);
        }

    }
```

Could someone provide some guidance as to how to set the visibility of panel based on the cookie values? Thanks

Comment: What's the code for the show/hide button?

Comment: All you're saving appears to be the id of the pnlSaveContent control. What values are you wanting to save?

Comment: FYI this is a follow up from his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592139/store-the-contents-of-a-panel-control-into-a-cookie). @user1724708, this still seems to be lacking needed information... I'm assuming you are trying to save the contents of the panel into the cookie, which is not what you should be doing. Just save the visibility `(true/false)` of each panel into the cookie.

Comment: ... and then on page load, if the cookie exists, set the panel visibilities based on the contents of the cookie, like what my previous answer was doing (somewhat). Or skip the saving and postbacks and just do it all via javascript.

Comment: To save the visibility of the pnlWeatherAppCtrl.ID (which holds the contents of the weather app) into the cookie, instead of   c.Values["savePg"] = pnlWeatherAppCtrl.ID; should I do something like the following: c.Values["savePg"] = pnlWeatherAppCtrl.Visible; ? How would I store the visibility state of panel control into a cookie?

Comment: @user1724708 depends on your show/hide logic. If you are doing it in javascript, you'd probably also need to set a hidden field with the value of the state of the panel so you can read it from the code behind. You could set it to whatever like 1=visible, 0=hidden and set `c.Values["wxPanel"]` and `c.Values["stockPanel"]`.